# R markdown running tex file error regarding toprule

Tags: r, latex, markdown

I have the following chunk of codes in markdown file

```
---
title: "Ag Productivity"
author: "Abdullah Mamun"
date: '2022-06-23'
output: 
 pdf_document:
  includes:
   in_header: "table1.tex"
---
```

and in .tex file I have this

```
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{lccc}
  \toprule
  & Model 1 & Model 2 & Model 3\\
\midrule
lag(YGrowth, 1) & \num{1.000}(\num{0.000})*** & \num{-0.347}(\num{0.030})*** & \num{-0.436}(\num{0.068})***\\
lag(Inputs, 1) & \num{0.000}(\num{0.000}) & \num{-0.100}(\num{0.127}) & \num{2.321}(\num{1.078})*\\
lag(GDPGR, 1) & \num{0.000}(\num{0.000})* & \num{0.270}(\num{0.069})*** & \num{0.341}(\num{0.531})\\
lag(lnPDENS, 1) & \num{0.000}(\num{0.000}) & \num{-0.124}(\num{0.031})*** & \num{0.158}(\num{0.076})*\\
lag(GRRAT, 1) & \num{0.000}(\num{0.000}) & \num{-0.280}(\num{0.095})** & \num{0.858}(\num{0.378})*\\
lag(EMPGR, 1) & \num{0.000}(\num{0.000})* & \num{0.317}(\num{0.138})* & \num{0.708}(\num{1.571})\\
\midrule
Num.Obs. & \num{1070} & \num{1025} & \\
R2 & \num{1.000} & \num{0.141} & \\
R2 Adj. & \num{1.000} & \num{0.076} & \\
AIC & \num{-79950.8} & \num{-2904.1} & \\
BIC & \num{-79781.6} & \num{-2911.2} & \\
RMSE & \num{0.00} & \num{0.06} & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I get this error message:

! Undefined control sequence. l.106   \toprule

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you show your table1.tex file? Does it include the `booktabs` and `siunitx` packages?

Comment: table1.tex file is above, in the code related .tex. No it doesn't include booktabs or siunitx. Do do I need to include them?

Comment: The table can't be in the header, it should be in the body. Even if you try to force latex to start the document early, that won't work because markdown is inserting preamble only command  after the `in_header` stuff. This will explode spectacularly

Comment: then please suggest where should I include this table1.tex file? something like this 

```{r, include=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
\input{table1.tex}   
```

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- the table does not belong in the header. You should move it to the body of the document. Even though you try to force the body to start early with `\begin{document}`, this won't work because rmarkdown will include preamble-only stuff after this
- if you want to use special macros like `\toprule` or `\num` you must load the package which provide them
- your table is missing a floating specifier that tells latex where the table can be placed, I suggest `[htbp`

rmarkdown file:

```
---
title: "Ag Productivity"
author: "Abdullah Mamun"
date: '2022-06-23'
output: 
 pdf_document:
   keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{booktabs}
  - \usepackage{siunitx}
---

\include{table1}
```

table1.tex:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{lccc}
  \toprule
  & Model 1 & Model 2 & Model 3\\
\midrule
lag(YGrowth, 1) & \num{1.000}(\num{0.000})*** & \num{-0.347}(\num{0.030})*** & \num{-0.436}(\num{0.068})***\\
lag(Inputs, 1) & \num{0.000}(\num{0.000}) & \num{-0.100}(\num{0.127}) & \num{2.321}(\num{1.078})*\\
lag(GDPGR, 1) & \num{0.000}(\num{0.000})* & \num{0.270}(\num{0.069})*** & \num{0.341}(\num{0.531})\\
lag(lnPDENS, 1) & \num{0.000}(\num{0.000}) & \num{-0.124}(\num{0.031})*** & \num{0.158}(\num{0.076})*\\
lag(GRRAT, 1) & \num{0.000}(\num{0.000}) & \num{-0.280}(\num{0.095})** & \num{0.858}(\num{0.378})*\\
lag(EMPGR, 1) & \num{0.000}(\num{0.000})* & \num{0.317}(\num{0.138})* & \num{0.708}(\num{1.571})\\
\midrule
Num.Obs. & \num{1070} & \num{1025} & \\
R2 & \num{1.000} & \num{0.141} & \\
R2 Adj. & \num{1.000} & \num{0.076} & \\
AIC & \num{-79950.8} & \num{-2904.1} & \\
BIC & \num{-79781.6} & \num{-2911.2} & \\
RMSE & \num{0.00} & \num{0.06} & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works, with a slight modification. \include{table1.tex}. I think that was a typo.

Comment: @AbdullahMamun `\include` does not need a file type. Latex will automatically add the `.tex`

Comment: Yes, you are right. It gave me error first time but now it is no more. Thanks a lot.

Comment: new problem arises. I have nine such .tex files and included all line by line. I see only first tables are in pdf output, but rest are showing blank. I placed them in this way: 

\include{table1}
\include{table2}
.. 

I also see each has .aux files. Is that a problem?

Comment: @AbdullahMamun If you have a new problem, please use the "Ask question" button to ask a new question

Comment: I could solve it using 'input' instead of 'include'. Now it works. Thanks